# managed identity for this assignment does not have the appropriate permissions to remediate these resources. Edit Assignment page and re-save it

Tags: azure, azure-powershell, azure-policy

I have a requirement of creating policy assignment from policy initiative and do remediation. I can create assignment using the below command.

```
$newRgAssignment = New-AzPolicyAssignment -Name $assigName -PolicySetDefinition $policySet -PolicyParameterObject $Params -AssignIdentity -Location 'westus' -scope $rgscope -DisplayName $assigName
```

In this I can create assignment successfully. while trying to remediation manually in I can see the below error message in azure portal .

```
The managed identity for this assignment does not have the appropriate permissions to remediate these resources. To add these permissions, go to the Edit Assignment page for this Policy and re-save it.
```

I tried creating a policy assignment by passing SystemAssigned identity type but ran into same problem.

I have left with only one option that is UserAssigned identity type. To pass this parameter we need to get the assigned user identity . To get the user identity I used the below commands

```
Set-AzContext -Subscription 'XYZ-123-ABC'
$UserAssignedIdentity = Get-AzUserAssignedIdentity
```

But no use.

Can any one help me on this issue. Any help can be appriciated.
Thank you.

Comment: Is this the same you are looking for , [**MICROSOFT DOCUMENTATION**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.resources/New-Azpolicyassignment?view=azps-8.0.0#example-6-policy-assignment-with-a-user-assigned-managed-identity)

Comment: @AjayKumarGhose-MT Thanks for your quick response . I am using the same link, but I am unable to get assigned user assigned identity

Comment: What is the error are you getting .

Comment: TenantId 'xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx' contains more than one active subscription. First one will be selected for further use. To select another subscription, use Set-AzContext. This is not any error. Its a warning. Get-AzUserAssignedIdentity command returning null

Comment: Do you have installed `Az.ManagedServiceIdentity` ,If not please try to `Install-Module -Name Az.ManagedServiceIdentity` .And make sure that the subscription and the account you have choose correctly. We can able to get the results at our end .

Answer (score 0):

> TenantId 'xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx' contains more than one active
> subscription. First one will be selected for further use. To select
> another subscription, use Set-AzContext. This is not any error. Its a
> warning. Get-AzUserAssignedIdentity command returning null.

We have tried with below cmd after installing module `Az.ManagedSericeIdentity` and can able to get the results.

Warning you might receive but after `Set-AzContext -Subscription 'XYZ-123-ABC'`
it will be logged into the correct subscription you wanted to.

[image]

*After successfully login type `$UserAssignedIdentity` even if you have user role to that subscription*.

[image]

For more information please refer the below links:-

- ***MS DOC***| [**`Get-AzUserAssignedIdentity`**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.managedserviceidentity/get-azuserassignedidentity?view=azps-8.0.0)
- [**SO THREAD**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61038360/errors-using-get-azuserassignedidentity-on-module-0-7-3-and-0-7-2-extended-ver) .