# Policy is not deploying because managed identity does not have permissions

Tags: azure, backup, policy

I am using the policy listed below. The roles are set for VM Contributor and Backup Contributor. When performing a remediation, I get the following warning message, "The managed identity for this assignment does not have the appropriate permissions to remediate these resources. To add these permissions, go to the Edit Assignment page for this Policy and re-save it." I have not altered the policy from its builtin policy. I have made sure to set the scope, tag name and value, and recovery service vault & policy.

Policy Name: [Configure backup on virtual machines with a given tag to an existing recovery services vault in the same location]

I have tried remediating the policy, but am given the same error. I have checked the policy definition and assignment to double check everything.

Comment: The administration and operation of policies and the permissions to make them work, I think is not a question about programming, it is more oriented to environment configuration... DevOps?

Answer (score 0):

The error you encountered indicates that the managed identity associated with the policy assignment does not have the required permissions to remediate the resources. To remediate the resources, the managed identity needs to be assigned the minimum `RBAC` role required for resource remediation.

I followed the steps below to assign the `'Configure backup on virtual machines with a given tag to an existing recovery services vault in the same location'` policy to a specific scope

1. I assigned the `Resource Policy Contributor` role to user at the `subscription` level

[image]

2. I assigned the policy to the `subscription` scope and specified all the required parameters as follows.

[image]

3. I selected `Create a remediation task` and `created a managed identity` under the **Remediation** section

[image]

4. After filling in all the details, click on create to assign the policy.

The policy assignment with a remediation task was created successfully as below.

[image]

Reference:   [Fix and cleanup MSI role assignments for policy assignments at the management group level](https://automate.guru/fix-msi-role-assignment/) &    [Stack link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72729229/managed-identity-for-this-assignment-does-not-have-the-appropriate-permissions-t) by `AjayKumarGhose`

Comment: Thank you for this information. I found out what my issue was. I did not have the correct permission in the subscription I was trying to assign the policy to. I was missing the permission to create a managed identity.